# How to automatically arrange ER diagram in draw.io

Tags: diagram, draw.io

I have created an ER diagram in draw.IO. However, my diagram is a bit of a mess and I have relational lines between tables cris-crossing each other at some places.

Is there a feature in draw.io that will automatically arrange the layout to be the most efficient and compact.

Answer (score 0):

draw.io supports layout change via Arrange > Layout
TBH I am not sure it will work correctly with ER but worth trying.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it first, but it didn't work properly so I was wondering if there is some other way.